# JavaCC Generates Dead Code

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javacc

I'm using JavaCC for the first time and I'm noticing it's generating a lot of dead code. There are many lines that look like (pardon the spacing, it's automatic):

```
{if ("" != null) return result;}
    throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");
  }
```

Is it possible to avoid generating this dead code? It causes tens of compiler warnings that are hopefully avoidable.

Thanks!

Here's a full minimal example from the .jj file:

```
Statement UseStatement():
{
    String dbName;
}
{
    <USE> dbName=DbObjectName()
    {
        return new UseStatement(dbName);
    }
}
```

Which generates:

```
final public Statement UseStatement() throws ParseException {String dbName;
    jj_consume_token(USE);
    dbName = DbObjectName();
{if ("" != null) return new UseStatement(dbName);}
    throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");
  }
```

Additionally JavaCC is generating a ParserTokenManager file which throws a TokenMgrError - but the code doesn't compile. It declares a `protected int curChar` where it should declare it a `char`. Googling this phrase shows many examples where it is correctly declared a `char` - is this just a lot of people hand-editing the result?

Comment: What version of JavaCC are you using?
Did you try the `LEGACY_EXCEPTION_HANDLING = false` option?

Comment: To answer your question about the type of `curChar`, no, it's not a lot of hand-editing. Version 5 generates the type as `char`.

Comment: LEGACY_EXCEPTION_HANDLING is actually not "user settable" but it is possible to get it to change - see my edit below.  The version that was being used by the Maven plugin I was using was 6.1.3, but I figured out how to move back to the original codehaus plugin and force its JavaCC version to 7.x.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the source and to prevent the dead code you have to trigger `Options.isLegacyExceptionHandling`.

```
  // Add if statement to prevent subsequent code generated
  // from being dead code.
  // NB: eclipse now detects 'if (true)' as dead code, so use the more complicated
  // 'if ("" != null)'
  if (inAction  && (Options.isLegacyExceptionHandling()) ) {
    t.image = "{if (\"\" != null) return";
    jumpPatched = true;
  }
```

which then triggers:

```
if (p.isJumpPatched() && !voidReturn) {
  if (isJavaDialect) {
    // TODO :: I don't think we need to throw an Error/Exception to mark that a return statement is missing as the compiler will flag this error automatically
    if (Options.isLegacyExceptionHandling()) {
        codeGenerator.genCodeLine("    throw new "+(Options.isLegacyExceptionHandling() ? "Error" : "RuntimeException")+"(\"Missing return statement in function\");");
    }
  } else {
    codeGenerator.genCodeLine("    throw \"Missing return statement in function\";");
  }
}
```

https://github.com/javacc/javacc/blob/e38cbdb1db7ca8bd66f892859fef88b4876e69ba/src/main/javacc/JavaCC.jj#L2771-L2779

https://github.com/javacc/javacc/blob/2ac628df1f899fdf6acf1f87fad313b6797085f7/src/main/java/org/javacc/parser/ParseEngine.java#L707-L712

Legacy exception handling is a derived option that is false only when `JAVA_TEMPLATE_TYPE=modern`.  The only way to get it set correctly is to include it in the `options` block in the .jj file as so:

```
options {
    JAVA_TEMPLATE_TYPE="modern";
}
```

In theory it is also settable via the command line options, but as of this writing it's actually impossible to set the derived option before the command line arguments are parsed ([#25](https://github.com/javacc/javacc/issues/25))

Comment: Is there a way to turn off 'legacy exception handling'?

Comment: Yes - see my edits. It's a little nuts but I got it eventually.